# How to check that Properties.Settings.Default.<field> of an int type is not null or empty in c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, null, int

I have a `Properties.Settings.Default.DateRetentionInDays` field in my settings/config file for a c# console app.  It is an int type.  If that field is null, the program crashes with an error indicating that I need to check to see if it is null before calling the method. I've tried a few ways to check if it is null, but none have worked.

I know how to do this for a string data type, and see some useful things to try for int data type for java, but not seeing the solution for an int data type in c#.

I tried the following because not only should the field not be null, it also needs to be < than 0, but it failed with the same error:  `if (Properties.Settings.Default.DateRetentionInDays >= 0)`.

Comment: Please put the code in your question!

Comment: What code?  There is a lot of code in the program.  The field I'm talking about is DateRetentionInDays:

Comment: @CasieOwen the code pertaining to your question/ issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open your settings in the designer and make sure `Value` column for the `DateRetentionInDays` property is not empty. You need to put some number there (presumably valid) to serve as default value for the property.

There is no other way because the code is auto generated.